# Trouble sorting through API response

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

I have an api call that shows the following response:

```
{'hits': {'hits': [{'_id': '-PAWFFyQVK-uQoknN97g5Q',
                    '_source': {'type': 'ip-src',
                                'value': {'comment': '',
                                          'ip-src': '37.152.183.70'}},
                    '_type': '_doc'},
                   {'_id': 'SOaFWLWHXMO6c8YaE2nYzw',
                    '_source': {'type': 'ip-src',
                                'value': {'comment': '',
                                          'ip-src': '91.218.114.30'}},
                    '_type': '_doc'},
                   {'_id': 'dl1Z28I2WqGDMB9DSsZXeQ',
                    '_source': {'type': 'ip-src',
                                'value': {'comment': '',
                                          'ip-src': '91.218.114.31'}},
                    '_type': '_doc'},
                   {'_id': '7_d1XO8BWWmwj0fG1lWgDA',
                    '_source': {'type': 'ip-src',
                                'value': {'comment': '',
                                          'ip-src': '170.130.55.112'}},
                    '_type': '_doc'}],
          'max_score': 0.0,
          'total': 4},
 'timed_out': False,
 'took': 1227}
```

I would like to just show the ip_srcs value in the response. Is there a simple way to do that. Ive been going through the json docs for help, but still not making much progress

Comment: What is the *specific* problem? The output is just an ordinary python dict containing other dicts and lists, which is easy enough to filter yourself.

Comment: I'mhaving trouble filtering the dict, but I what I want to do is just show the ip-src and value, so it only shows those values going straight down line . For example: 
ip-src: 00.11.222.33.44, and another like that below it and so on

Answer (score 0):

if you're familiar with pandas you can do this and manipulate the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
In [151]: pd.json_normalize(results['hits']['hits'])
Out[151]:
                      _id _type _source.type _source.value.comment _source.value.ip-src
0  -PAWFFyQVK-uQoknN97g5Q  _doc       ip-src                              37.152.183.70
1  SOaFWLWHXMO6c8YaE2nYzw  _doc       ip-src                              91.218.114.30
2  dl1Z28I2WqGDMB9DSsZXeQ  _doc       ip-src                              91.218.114.31
3  7_d1XO8BWWmwj0fG1lWgDA  _doc       ip-src                             170.130.55.112
```

Or you can traverse the response to the list that you want, and loop:

```
In [164]: ip_list = []
     ...: for ip in results['hits']['hits']:
     ...:     #print(ip['_source']['value']['ip-src'])
     ...:     ip_list.append(ip['_source']['value']['ip-src'])
     

In [165]: ip_list
Out[165]: ['37.152.183.70', '91.218.114.30', '91.218.114.31', '170.130.55.112']
```

list comprehension works too (alternate way to writing a for loop)

```
In [167]: ip_list = [ip['_source']['value']['ip-src'] for ip in results['hits']['hits']]

In [168]: ip_list
Out[168]: ['37.152.183.70', '91.218.114.30', '91.218.114.31', '170.130.55.112']
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple approach to get the results you need;

```
data = source['hits']['hits']
result = {}

for index,item  in enumerate(data):
    temp = {}
    temp['ip-src'] = item['_source']['value']['ip-src']
    result[index]=temp

print(result)
```

Output:

[image]

`source` is your raw data.

Comment: Awesome. thanks for explaining that. How would I approach it if I just wanted to show only unique ip_srcs and values?